# How can I convert a given ASCII value to corresponding character in Velocity Template?

Tags: java, velocity, apache-fop

I want to convert a given ASCII value to the corresponding character in a FOP template using velocity.

> For Eg: I want ASCII value of 65 to get converted to A

I have tried putting a Character Object in the velocity context and then used Character.toChars(int) but velocity printed its address instead of the the corresponding character, can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong. Or is there a better way to do it.

> In velocity context:
> `VelocityContext.put("char", new Character());`
>
> In FOP Template
> `set($asciiValue = 65)`
> `$char.toChars($asciiValue)`

Comment: ASCII value 0x41 (65 if you wish) is the character A.  Why do you need to convert it?

Comment: the template creates a single image which is a collection of images. I need to put an alphabetic identifier on each image in the collection, on the basis of ordering they will appear on the final image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass your custom converter to Velocity context (as you pass Character object). But also you can change your code to this:

```
#set ($string = " ")
#set ($asciiValue = 65)
#set ($chars = $char.toChars($asciiValue))
#set ($letter = $string.copyValueOf($chars)) 
$letter
```

`copyValueOf` is used for create String from char array.